# Which problems is html5 template tag going to solve?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

After reading about [html5 template tag](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) I started to think what kind of problems is it going to solve and how exactly will it make the web better.

It is not hard to get main ideas from the article:

- content is inert (no image/video uploads, no scripts run)
- can not accidentally manipulate template while it is in inert state
- you can place it everywhere and grab it later

But each of these things has a drawback:

- content is inert. This means that there is no way to preload my images (I also do not think that a lot of people put js scripts inside of their template)
- can not manipulate template. This means you can not precompile it like you can do with handlebars
- you can place it everywhere. But I was able to place `<script type='txt/template'>..</script>` everywhere as well.

So how is html5-template is going to address the problems of **painful styling and theming** which are stated in offscreen DOM technique or **Security issues (XSS vulnurabilities)** which are stated in Overloading script?